# node.js - Regex: Put space between triple mustaches ( {{{ => { {{ )

Tags: node.js, regex, handlebars.js

I have a String which contains minified CSS and handlebars.js notations (if statements, variables and so on). Because that the String is minified, it also contains stuff like `'{{{' or '}}}'` which I need to replace with `'{ {{' or '}} }'` (put one space between) in order to compile it correctly through handlebars.

Trouble is that I cannot manage to put the correct Regex together for this simple task. I guess the { symbols make the whole thing difficult since its a Regex-specific character.

String:

```
.class1{{{#if style.textColor}}color:{{style.textColor}};{{/if}}}item-price{{{#if style.showPrice}}display:block;{{else}}display:none;{{/if}}{{#if style.fontSizeItemPrice}}font-size:{{style.fontSizeItemPrice}}px;{{/if}}}
```

Expected output:

```
.class1{ {{#if style.textColor}}color:{{style.textColor}};{{/if}} }item-price{ {{#if style.showPrice}}display:block;{{else}}display:none;{{/if}}{{#if style.fontSizeItemPrice}}font-size:{{style.fontSizeItemPrice}}px;{{/if}} }
```

Simply substituting triple mustaches works, but only for the first occurance:

```js
css = css.replace("{{{", "{ {{");
css = css.replace("}}}", "}} }")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String.replace function automatically converts the first string param to regex (without the global option set). That's why only the first occurrence is replaced. If you want to replace all occurrences of the pattern, you can create a regex with global option set. Try the following snippet.

`css = css.replace(/{{{/g, '{ {{').replace(/}}}/g, '}} }')`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Matching the string globally was indeed whats missing.